# Segfaults with Intel Intrinsics

Tags: c, intel, sse, intrinsics, memory-alignment

I have the following function using Intel intrinsics:

```
int c_lattice_worker( int lm, double* inArr, double* outArr, int arrLen,
             double sin_,  double cos_ ) {
  int xi, yi;
  double x, y;
  __m128d _msin, _mcos;
  __m128d _m0, _m1;
  _msin = _mm_loaddup_pd( &sin_ );
  _mcos = _mm_loaddup_pd( &cos_ );

  for ( int xnc = lm; xnc < (arrLen - (lm << 1)); xnc += 2 ) {
    _m0 = _mm_load_pd( &inArr[ xnc ] );
    _m1 = _mm_shuffle_pd( _m0, _m0, 0x1 );
    _m0 = _mm_mul_pd( _msin, _m0 );
    _m1 = _mm_mul_pd( _mcos, _m1 );
    _m0 = _mm_addsub_pd( _m0, _m1 );
    _mm_store_sd( &outArr[ xnc + 1 ], _m0 ); // segfault here if lm == 1
    _m1 = _mm_shuffle_pd( _m0, _m0, 0x1 );
    _mm_store_sd( &outArr[ xnc     ], _m1 ); // segfault here if lm == 1
    }
  }

  // fliping the lm modifier
  return 1 - lm;
}
```

Arrays `inArr` and `outArr` have even length, `lm` is either 0 or 1. If it is 0 then everything works correctly, but if `lm` is 1 then `_mm_store_sd` cause the program to segfault (or, to put it differently, commenting out both of these lines makes the segfault go away). For `lm == 1` the `xnc` index is not aligned to 16 bytes, but according to Intel's documentation 16-byte alignment is not required for `_mm_store_sd`, only for `_mm_store_pd`. I am clueless. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that:

1. I can use `_mm_storeu_pd` to store two packed 64-bit floats into unaligned memory address.
2. But when I do this I must also use `_mm_loadu_pd` to load from unaligned memory address.

So in fact `_mm_load_pd` was causing the segfault but when I commented out the store operations it got optimized away because it was dead code.